# JHipster best way to update entity field when another is called

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jhipster

I used jHipster to generate stock management project, and i want to update Product quantity field whenever i do a Transaction (selling product [create, update, and delete]).

So, is it better (best practices) to create a web service in my Product resource (backend) called updateProductQuantity and call it in my angular when user do transaction, or do it in the backend and update database using only java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this question was going to be too broad, but the thing you ask has only a way to go as a best practice. If you're going to store the product quantity as a field, your best is to implement a `private` method (preferably in the product service, but could be in the resource class if you don't use services) and call it either when you perform a product creation or deletion.

This is a **backend related task**, as the frontend should never worry about domain/DB business logic. You've got a good reference [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/322648/97167):

> You should put the business logic which is tied to front-end to the
>   front-end application and stuff like validation, login, ie. operations
>   which need to be run against the database, in the back-end. For
>   front-end many of the business rules could consist of user interface
>   indicators, such as if number of products is less than 5, display the
>   product with red headline and notification, that the stock is low.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is very clear and you gived me a good example.